# Windows .NET Application not opening After Power failure. In Event viewer showing Not getting Value from My.Settings

Tags: windows, vb.net, forms, visual-studio-2017, desktop-application

I am working on one VB.NET Based SCADA System. My application working fine on all my machines. When there is sudden power failure or shutdown after we start system application not opening. In Event viewer Showing Following Error. There R_LOT_SIZE is MY.Setting Variable. If My.setting property holds any value and we shutdown system getting this error.

`The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info: System.Xml.XmlException at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(System.Exception) at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(System.String, System.String[]) at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseText(Int32 ByRef, Int32 ByRef, Int32 ByRef) at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseText() at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent() at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read() at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read() at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Skip() at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Skip() at System.Configuration.XmlUtil.StrictSkipToNextElement(System.Configuration.ExceptionAction) at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ScanSectionsRecursive(System.Configuration.XmlUtil, System.String, Boolean, System.String, System.Configuration.OverrideModeSetting, Boolean) at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ScanSectionsRecursive(System.Configuration.XmlUtil, System.String, Boolean, System.String, System.Configuration.OverrideModeSetting, Boolean) at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ScanSections(System.Configuration.XmlUtil) at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.InitConfigFromFile() Exception Info: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean) at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors) at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfInitErrors() at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.OnConfigRemoved(System.Object, System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigEventArgs) Exception Info: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.OnConfigRemoved(System.Object, System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigEventArgs) at System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigRoot.OnConfigRemoved(System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigEventArgs) at System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigRoot.RemoveConfigImpl(System.String, System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord) at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(System.String, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, System.Object ByRef, System.Object ByRef) at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(System.String) at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(System.String) at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(System.String) at System.Configuration.ClientSettingsStore.ReadSettings(System.String, Boolean) at System.Configuration.LocalFileSettingsProvider.GetPropertyValues(System.Configuration.SettingsContext, System.Configuration.SettingsPropertyCollection) at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.GetPropertiesFromProvider(System.Configuration.SettingsProvider) at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.GetPropertyValueByName(System.String) at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.get_Item(System.String) at System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.GetPropertyValue(System.String) at System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.get_Item(System.String) at FX3U_PLC.My.MySettings.get_R_LOT_SIZE() at FX3U_PLC.MainNew.InitializeComponent() at FX3U_PLC.MainNew..ctor() Exception Info: System.InvalidOperationException at FX3U_PLC.My.MyProject+MyForms.Create__Instance__[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.__Canon) at FX3U_PLC.My.MyProject+MyForms.get_MainNew() at FX3U_PLC.My.MyApplication.OnCreateMainForm() at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun() at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel() at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(System.String[]) at FX3U_PLC.My.MyApplication.Main(System.String[])`

Comment: Have you checked to see if the XML file has become corrupted?

Comment: On Event Viewer

Comment: Is this the third time you have asked this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by deleting user.config file. Thank you..

Comment: If your problem has been solved, so please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).